# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context

Tags: java, android, class

guys i make this new class but when i call this function vibrate in Main Activity i have error

```
public class vibrate  extends Activity{

public void vibrate() {
        try {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            } else {
                //deprecated in API 26
                v.vibrate(200);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and this how i called this class

```
 vibrate v = new vibrate() ;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        v.vibrate();
       
    }
```

this is the error

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `vibrate` is a subclass of Activity, when you create an instance like this, you are creating an activity. But it's not a right way to create an activity.

```
vibrate v = new vibrate()
```

You have to declare your activity inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and invoke the activity by using intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, vibrate.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But to use the Vibrator, you just need to do like this.

```
public class VibrateActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vibrate();
    }

    private void vibrate() {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (vibrator != null) {
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            } else {
                //deprecated in API 26
                v.vibrate(200);
            }
        }
}
```

Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**UPDATE:**
Use separate class without doing in the activity.

```
public class Vibrate extends Activity {

    public void vibrate(Context context) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (vibrator != null) {
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            } else {
                //deprecated in API 26
                v.vibrate(200);
            }
        }
}
```

And use it like this in your activity.

```
Vibrate vibrate = new Vibrate();
vibrate.vibrate(this)
```

Comment: Yes, in my example `VibrateActivity` is same as your `MainActivity`, you don't need to create another activity to do that.

Comment: But there is a problem I don't won't to move to vibrate activity(make intent) i need to run the all functions inside vibrate class but in `MainActivity.java` i don't won't to make intent so what is the best way to just declare vibrate class inside `MainActivity.java `and use his functions

Comment: Just create a class, let's say `Vibrate`, without extends from Activity. And inside only has one method called vibrate too.

Comment: i have done this before but when i try to but function like this `protected void onResume()` it's not working and i have a lot of errors for that i used `extends Activity`  and also have error with `getSystemService` is vibrate function

Comment: It's difficult to explain, please check my UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize  vibrate v = new vibrate(); in onCreate()
and call  v.vibrate();
No need to make vibrate as an Activity.